# Batch File String Comparison not working

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to detect a change in a file using a looping windows batch file using md5. For some reason the comparison is failing even though the strings are identical.

I can't tell where I'm going wrong, the strings look identical

```
@echo off

IF NOT DEFINED md5_sum_initial (for /f "delims=" %%i in ('md5 -n MetricsBoard.pptx') do set md5_sum_initial=%%i )

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('md5 -n MetricsBoard.pptx') do set md5_sum_current=%%i

echo %md5_sum_initial%
echo %md5_sum_current%

IF "%md5_sum_initial%"=="%md5_sum_current%" (
  ECHO True
) ELSE (
  ECHO False
)
```

**Output**

> 7F8583E345ED7C10823B9C93985270AA
>   7F8583E345ED7C10823B9C93985270AA
>   False

Comment: I would change your SET commands to this format. `set "md5_sum_initial=%%i"`  Most likely adding a trailing space.

Comment: I'm sure that one of the values has a trailing space -- check out with `echo "%md5_sum_initial%"`...

Comment: @Squashman that fixed it. I'm baffled. Do you know what the underlying issue is?

Comment: @canyon289 - `do set md5_sum_initial=%%i )` the space before your `)` is the problem.

Comment: there is a space too much. Change `echo %md5_sum_initial%` to `echo -%md5_sum_initial%-` and you'll see it. It's in `do set md5_sum_initial=%%i )`. Squashman's way of using quotes avoids that type of "typing error"

Comment: Thanks all. 1 minute of SO is more effective than 1 hour of keyboard mashing, Much appreciated!